# C++11 alias template as template template argument in specialization?

Tags: c++, c++11

Why doesn't the follow C++11 program compile?

```
template<template<typename> class X, typename Y> struct C;
template<template<typename> class X, typename Z> struct C<X, X<Z>> {};

template<typename T> using A = T*;

int main()
{
    C<A, A<int>> c;
}
```

The error is:

```
aggregate ‘C<A, int*> c’ has incomplete type and cannot be defined
```

**Why doesn't the partial specialization of `C` match `C<A, A<int>>`?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I *think* that 14.5.7 Alias templates:

> When a *template-id* refers to the specialization of an alias template, it is equivalent to the associated type obtained by substitution of its *template-arguments* for the *template-parameters* in the *type-id* of the alias template.

would apply, so `X<Z>` would be interpreted as `Z*` as soon as `X` is known to be an alias template. The syntax for a partial specialisation does indeed use the *template-id* grammar rule. However, template argument substitution takes place as the last step in template argument deduction, only once all template arguments have been deduced.

> **14.5.5.1 Matching of class template partial specializations [temp.class.spec.match]**
>
> 2 A partial specialization matches a given actual template argument list if the template arguments of the partial specialization can be deduced from the actual template argument list (14.8.2).
>
> **14.8.2 Template argument deduction [temp.deduct]**
>
> 5 When all template arguments have been deduced or obtained from default template arguments, all uses of template parameters in the template parameter list of the template and the function type are replaced with the corresponding deduced or default argument values.

Without template argument substitution of `X`, `Z` cannot be deduced. So, the specialisation does not match.

Comment: Is it your conclusion that my OP program is well-formed?

Comment: @AndrewTomazos Yes, I think so, but I should add that I'm not entirely convinced of that.

Comment: There's also a note: "An alias template name is never deduced." Maybe that applies?

Comment: @KerrekSB I see, my answer is significantly different from the alias template case. My example only requires deduction of `T`, so it's not really a perfect analogy. Will check further.

Comment: Related: https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/std-discussion/DLSC_m2vF4s

Comment: Standard quote for "However, template argument substitution takes place as the last step in template argument deduction, only once all template arguments have been deduced."?

Comment: @AndrewTomazos I think my original answer was wrong, and have changed my "Yes" to a "No".

Comment: @KerrekSB yes that applies. Note that the argument already makes that impossible, because `A<int>` is `int*`. It's not so much the parameter in the specialization that is the problem... it still has the form `X<Z>`. For example, the following still fails http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/26493b1e499ba0b4 even though both `X` and `Z` are deduced (because the form `int*` does not match the form `X<Z>`). But if you say `typename identity<X<Z>>::type` instead of `X<Z>`, the code is accepted.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I managed to get really confused by your comment, but if I do understand you correctly now, what you mean is that `X` is deduced both from `A` and from `A<int>`. Deduction from `A` succeeds, but deduction from `A<int>` fails (because that is `int *`), and all deductions must lead to the same type. For the same reason, `template <typename T> void f(T, T *); int main() { f(0, 0); }` is also rejected: the first argument would cause `T` to be deduced as `int`, but the `T` in the second parameter type cannot be deduced from the second argument. Is that a fair comparison?

Comment: I would like to just call this a "non-deducible context", because that would be very easy to understand and reason about, since all the same arguments apply as to real non-deducible contexts (e.g. `typename id<T>::type` etc.), but I couldn't find alias templates explicitly listed as non-deducible contexts...

Comment: @KerrekSB It really isn't a non-deducible context. Non-deducible context applies to the template definition, where it isn't known whether the template template argument will be a template class or a template alias. Also, Johannes Schaub's example in the comments here shows how it works differently from non-deducible contexts.

Comment: @hvd: You're right ... anyway, deducibility applies to deduction, which isn't what happens when you specialize partially, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

`A<int>` *is* `int`, so `C<A, A<int>>` *is* `C<A, int>`. The specialization cannot match what you want because it cannot see `A<int>`.

Comment: At the same time, though, `X<Z>` (where `X` is `A`) *is* `Z`, so for matching the specialisation, it wouldn't need to see `A<int>`.

Answer (score 1):

`A` is an alias template, and it essentially specializes to a typedef-name. `A<int>` is like a typedef for `int *`.

`C<A, A<int>>` is the same as `C<A, int *>`. The parameter `X` gets `A` and the parameter `Y` gets `int *`. To deduce that `Z` in the partial specialization should be `int`, the compiler would have to inspect inside the alias definition. That is not how aliases work. The definition is a non-deduced context, even if substituting the alias definition into its indirect use `X<Z>` in the partial specialization would produce a deduced context. Moreover, that deduction would need to be done speculatively to determine that `A` can even be `X` in the first place. Tackling this problem would be a huge burden of complexity.

As you mentioned on the std-discussion list, "An alias template name is never deduced."